# Xamarin Firebase child non static

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I want to define a non static child in my firebase database. This child should be the value entered in the "Name" field of the application (here newUser.Text)

I did this for the first page but I can't access newUser.Text on the other pages. How can I do ?

```
public void OnNextPageButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    _ = firebaseClient.Child("Livret individuel de suivi pédagogique").Child(newUser.Text).PutAsync(new MyDatabaseRecord

    {
        Nom = newUser.Text,
        Prenom = newPrenom.Text,
        Email = newEmail.Text,
        CIS = newCIS.Text,
        Grade = newGrade.Text,
        DateRecrutement = newDateRecrutement.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
        DateNaissance = newDateNaissance.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
        Observations = newObservations.Text,



    });

    newUser.Text = "";
    newPrenom.Text = "";

    newDateNaissance.AutomationId = "";
    newCIS.Text = "";
    newGrade.Text = "";
    newDateRecrutement.AutomationId = "";
    newObservations.Text = "";


     Navigation.PushModalAsync(new page0());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Property`.

Define in Page11:

```
public partial class Page11 : ContentPage
{
    public string newUserText { get; set; }
    public Page11()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Usage in Page12:

```
public partial class Page12 : ContentPage
{
   
    public Page12()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var userText = new Page11().newUserText;
    }
}
```